# I've recently started receiving an error, can anyone help? "Resolve of invalid GC handle. The handle is from a previous domain."

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've recently started receiving the following error whenever I enter play mode in the Unity editor.

> Resolve of invalid GC handle. The handle is from a previous domain.
> The resolve operation is skipped. UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent
> (int,intptr,bool&)

This occurs every time I enter play mode, I'm not sure what I changed to cause this. The game still builds successfully without errors and I can't seem to find any issue with the game once built. It's worth mentioning that I may have noticed a slight dip in fps since I started getting the error. This is only while in play mode, not in the built player, although I might be imagining it, not sure.

I'm using version 2021.3.10f1, and recently updated from an earlier version, although have been using this version for around 2 weeks without issue.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you by chance using `static` **anywhere** in your `MonoBehaviour` scripts? When using `static` in Unity beware - [thar be dragons](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/DomainReloading.html).  Unity is a **CLR Host** whereby it can and will **zap** out the **Primary App Domain** along with all your objects **including singletons** not just during runtime but also whilst using the **Editor**.  See also _[Details of disabling Domain and Scene Reload](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfigurableEnterPlayModeDetails.html)_.  _"The handle is from a previous domain"_ is a hint.